# Date Conversion in specific format

Tags: java

I want to convert date to `dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.s` this format

I am getting system date using `Date d = new Date();`

I am try

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.s");
Date d = new Date();
String CALL_DATE = formatter2.format(d);
```

tats give me output is correct but when I am try to save it gives error:

```
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
```

so please suggest me about this solution.

Comment: Your code works fine and printed `12-Jul-2013 11:56:06.6`

Comment: Same here. What error are you getting?

Comment: Did'nt reproduce and  no stacktrace :voting to close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you posted this as an question.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.s");
Date d = new Date();
String CALL_DATE = formatter2.format(d);
```

This is working fine. If you wan to take date in other formats refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: when I am try to save it gives error:ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Comment: @AloNE are you sure that you get this error in the code **you** posted?

Comment: no not it give me correct output but at save time it gives an error.

Comment: That is a Oracle database error message when you are trying to commit. Not a issue in here. Refer this, may help you to solve oracle issue. http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_01830_date_format_picture_ends_before_converting_entire_input_string.htm

Comment: Are you trying to write the date to an Oracle database? You should make it more clear and tag appropriately, and include that part of the code. And comment at your own top post up there so everyone can see it better.

Comment: @AloNE check this out too, http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01830.php

Answer (score 3):

Strangely none of the answers point out that in order to print milliseconds, you have to use `dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.S`.

Notice the uppercase `S`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: OP's code works fine and printed 12-Jul-2013 11:56:06.6

Comment: Well it printed 06.6 because you have `s.s`. This couldn't be correct output! It just duplicates the seconds into milliseconds.

Comment: But OP is telling he got na error. +1 for the spot.

Answer (score 2):

Hm, the code that you posted works (and compiles) fine for me :) The only thing that I had to do is add some imports. Look:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.S");
        Date d = new Date();
        String CALL_DATE = formatter2.format(d);
        System.out.println(CALL_DATE);
    }
}
```

Also, like @adarshr said, you need to replace `s` with `S` to print milliseconds.

**Output:**

```
m4tx@m4tx-N56VZ:~/Desktop$ javac Test.java 
m4tx@m4tx-N56VZ:~/Desktop$ java Test
12-Jul-2013 08:30:41.935
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get help using any of these function by making some modifications as per you requirements.

```
public static Date getDatebyMilliSeconds(Long timeInMillis) {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
        Date date = cal.getTime();
        return date;
    }


    public static Date getDateByString(String str_date) {
        DateFormat formatter;
        Date date = new Date();
        try {
            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            date = (Date) formatter.parse(str_date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            logger.error("------- error in date conversion " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return date;
    }
```

You can use `date.getTime()` this will return time in miliseconds and then you can use 1 function i mentioned, and in same way by making some change you can use the 2nd one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..... your code is fine but i think you have made in mistake some other part of your code anyway use this below code to check it

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.text.*;

    public class Datedemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

      Date dNow = new Date( );
      SimpleDateFormat ft = 
      new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.S");

      System.out.println("Current Date: " + ft.format(dNow));
   }
}
```

**output**

```
Current Date: 12-Jul-2013 11:56:44.44
```